# less doesn't highlight search

Tags: less

Something happened so I don't see less highlights any more. I've tried:

- using different terminal.
- using `-g` option
- making sure `-G` isn't there
- ^K while searching
- <kbd>ESC</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd>

Nothing helps.

I work in Ubuntu 12.10 on an i3 desktop. `$TERM=screen-256`. When I use `^ ALT 1` to switch to **TTY1** and do `man man` I can see that it highlights there both man parameters and search patterns.

What else can I do to fix it ?

Comment: What did set the TERM variable to that value? Are you using screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The highlighting in TTY1 works since it sets the TERM variable to a proper value.

#### If you're using screen:

Change the TERM variable to a proper value (e.g., *screen* or *screen-256color*). Check your personal *~/.screenrc* or the system-wide */etc/screenrc* and fix the corresponding line.

In my version of less, the value *screen-256* should actually results in an error:

```
WARNING: terminal is not fully functional
-  (press RETURN)
```

#### If you're not using screen:

The *screen** only get interpreted correctly by screen.

The correct value for TERM depends on your terminal emulator and should usually get set by it. The default of Ubuntu's three pre-installed terminal emulators is *xterm*.

Execute

```
grep -R TERM= ~/.* /etc 2> /dev/null
```

the check if TERM's value gets overridden in your shell's configuration files.

Comment: echo $TERM in TTY1 reteruns 'screen-256 color' too. But changing TERM to 'xterm' highlights it again.

Answer (score 3):

Well this is annoying. What is going on here? (in `tmux` under `iTerm.app`)

```
$ echo test > test ; echo $TERM
screen
```

and then with some recording

```
$ script withscreen
Script started, output file is withscreen
$ less -p test test
... q to quit and then exit the shell session ...

$ script withxterm
Script started, output file is withxterm
$ TERM=xterm less -p test test
... q and exit again ...
```

and now we look at the codes used

```
$ grep test withscreen | hexdump -C
00000000  24 20 6c 65 73 73 20 2d  70 20 74 65 73 74 20 74  |$ less -p test t|
00000010  65 73 74 0d 0d 0a 1b 5b  33 6d 74 65 73 74 1b 5b  |est....[3mtest.[|
00000020  32 33 6d 0d 0a 1b 5b 35  3b 31 48 1b 5b 33 6d 74  |23m...[5;1H.[3mt|
00000030  65 73 74 1b 5b 32 33 6d  0d 0a 1b 5b 33 38 3b 31  |est.[23m...[38;1|
00000040  48 1b 5b 33 6d 74 65 73  74 20 28 45 4e 44 29 1b  |H.[3mtest (END).|
00000050  5b 32 33 6d 1b 5b 4b 0d  1b 5b 4b 1b 5b 3f 31 6c  |[23m.[K..[K.[?1l|
00000060  1b 3e 24 20 5e 44 0d 0d  0a                       |.>$ ^D...|
00000069
$ grep test withxterm | hexdump -C
00000000  24 20 54 45 52 4d 3d 78  74 65 72 6d 20 6c 65 73  |$ TERM=xterm les|
00000010  73 20 2d 70 20 74 65 73  74 20 74 65 73 74 0d 0d  |s -p test test..|
00000020  0a 1b 5b 37 6d 74 65 73  74 1b 5b 32 37 6d 0d 0a  |..[7mtest.[27m..|
00000030  1b 5b 35 3b 31 48 1b 5b  37 6d 74 65 73 74 1b 5b  |.[5;1H.[7mtest.[|
00000040  32 37 6d 0d 0a 1b 5b 33  38 3b 31 48 1b 5b 37 6d  |27m...[38;1H.[7m|
00000050  74 65 73 74 20 28 45 4e  44 29 1b 5b 32 37 6d 1b  |test (END).[27m.|
00000060  5b 4b 0d 1b 5b 4b 1b 5b  3f 31 6c 1b 3e 24 20 65  |[K..[K.[?1l.>$ e|
00000070  78 69 74 0d 0d 0a                                 |xit...|
00000076
$
```

the `1b 5b ...` codes may be rendered more intelligible by consulting the [xterm control sequences documentation](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) or one can fiddle around manually with the sequences to see which under `TERM=xterm` is causing the highlighting

```
$ printf "\033[7mtest\033[27m\n"
test
```

which the `TERM=screen` case does not do, per the control sequences docs that's an inverse

```
ESC [
     Control Sequence Introducer (CSI  is 0x9b).
...
CSI Pm m  Character Attributes (SGR).
...
            Ps = 7  -> Inverse.
...
            Ps = 2 7  -> Positive (not inverse).
```

and nearby from that document we might learn that the `screen` terminal `\033[3m` is for *Italicized* and `\033[23m` *Not italicized*.

This finding gives some options; we might configure the terminal to display italicized text, or we could instead try to make the `screen` terminal use the inverse codes instead of italics. (Some digging around in the `less(1)` docs did not show any clear "use inverse instead of italic" knobs to fiddle with.) (Also, some terminals may offer support for translating X to Y, check terminal docs for details.) (Or you could try a different terminal emulator and see what that one does...)

Wow italicized text is *ugly*. Let's try instead changing the codes `screen` uses to inverse. This obviously involves the `terminfo` (or possibly `termcap`) database, which can be exported via [`infocmp(1)`](http://man.openbsd.org/man1/infocmp.1) and compiled by [`tic(1)`](http://man.openbsd.org/man1/tic.1)

```
$ TERM=screen infocmp > ti.screen ; TERM=xterm infocmp > ti.xterm
$ fgrep '\E[7' ti.xterm
        rc=\E8, rep=%p1%c\E[%p2%{1}%-%db, rev=\E[7m, ri=\EM,
        smir=\E[4h, smkx=\E[?1h\E=, smm=\E[?1034h, smso=\E[7m,
$ fgrep rev= ti.screen
        nel=\EE, op=\E[39;49m, rc=\E8, rev=\E[7m, ri=\EM, rmacs=^O,
$ fgrep '\E[3m' ti.screen
        smso=\E[3m, smul=\E[4m, tbc=\E[3g,
$
```

So I'd guess the `smso` is being used given that `xterm` uses `\E[7m` and `screen` `\E[3m`; according to [`terminfo(5)`](http://man.openbsd.org/man5/terminfo.5) this is "standout mode" and is paired with the reverse `rmso`; let's change those to what `xterm` uses...

```
$ TERM=screen infocmp | sed -e 's/smso=[^,]*/smso=\\E[7m/;s/rmso=[^,]*/rmso=\\E[27m/' > foo
$ tic -o ~/.terminfo foo
$ rm foo
```

Hey that looks better now (but will have to be done on all hosts for the `screen` or whatever `terminfo` file...)